Deep linking is not working in Android 14+ devices
My website is hosted in local area network, and also deployed the assetlinks.json. I am able to access it through https://hostname/.well-known/assetlinks.json in the browser. However, I am still not able to launch my application through URL.
I am getting below response
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur package_name
package name : ID: dsc71988chksbkak008 Signatures: [valid signature] Domain verification state: hostname: 1024 User 0: Verification link handling allowed: true Selection state: Disabled: host name{}

NOTE - I'm able to launch application through the url in below android 12 version of devices.
I am expecting my application to be launched through URL.
